# addEventListener - как работает, особенности

Tags: javascript

как работает `addEventListener`? куда добавляет свои обработчики?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     alert(1);
});
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     alert(2);
});
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     alert(3);
});
```

если добавить таким образом, то вывод будет по порядку. в то время как если навешать прямо на `window.onload` - этого не будет

и что будет если сделать так -

```
window.addEventListener("super_foo_bar", function(){
            // ...
});
```

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под _куда добавляет свои обработчики_?

Comment: исправил вопрос

Comment: смотрели [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)?